# Avoiding code repetition when using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, refactoring

Ok so I have a number of methods that look like this:- which sorts a list by artist, album, year etc.

```
        public void SortByAlbum(SortOrder sortOrder)
        {
           if (sortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending)
              _list = _list.OrderBy(x => x.Album).ToList();
           else if (sortOrder == SortOrder.Descending)
              _list = _list.OrderByDescending(x => x.Album).ToList();
        }
```

and this:

```
        public void SortByArtist(SortOrder sortOrder)
        {
           if (sortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending)
              _list = _list.OrderBy(x => x.Artist).ToList();
           else if (sortOrder == SortOrder.Descending)
              _list = _list.OrderByDescending(x => x.Artist).ToList();
        }
```

Now obviously this isn't good code so it needs refactoring into one Sort() method but I just cant figure out how to do it in the simplest possible way. I don't care if it uses IComparer or LINQ.

I want it to look something like this:

```
    public void Sort(SortOrder sortOrder, SortType sortType)
    {
        //implementation here
    }

    public enum SortType
    {
       Artist,
       Album,
       Year
    }
```

So whats the cleanest way to do this with no code repetition?

Thanks, Lee

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to mimick the signature of the OrderBy extension method:

**Update 1** you have to be explicit in the first generic parameter to your keySelector Func. I'm going to take a guess at your type and call it "Song".

```
public void Sort<TKey>(SortOrder sortOrder,
                       Func<Song, TKey> keySelector)
{
    if (sortOrder == SortOrder.Descending)
    {
        _list = _list.OrderByDescending(keySelector).ToList(); 
    }
    else
    {
        _list = _list.OrderBy(keySelector).ToList(); 
    }
}
```

Now you can call "Sort" like this:

```
Sort(SortOrder.Descending, x => x.Album);
```

**Update 2**

Following up on Tom Lokhorst's comment: If you want to predefine some shorthand sort criteria, you could do so by defining a class like this:

```
public static class SortColumn
{
    public static readonly Func<Song, string> Artist = x => x.Artist;
    public static readonly Func<Song, string> Album = x => x.Album;
}
```

Now you can simply call:

```
Sort(SortOrder.Descending, SortColumn.Artist);
```

Comment: Also, if you, for some reason, don't want to write down the explicit lambda in the call to `Sort` (it could get big), you can create some sort of list with predefined `Func<TSource, TKey>` objects (equivalent to the enum in the example).

Comment: Funny I read that just this morning in the Linq in Action book

Comment: The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.OrderByDescending<TSource,TKey>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,TKey>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

On the orderby and orderbyDesc lines.

Comment: @Lee - is that before or after my edit a few minutes ago? I changed my code after testing it and discovering the same error.

Comment: Yeah posted that before I read your update, i've fixed the error and its working great. Thanks Matt.

Comment: How close was I with "Song" as the data type name? :)

Answer (score 2):

You might try using a [generic comparer](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dipenlama22/SortingUsingGeneric07052006081035AM/SortingUsingGeneric.aspx?ArticleID=dafdb8cc-fd02-4a4d-bd17-0c5785b1b91d).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add an extension method to `IList<T>`:

```
 public static class extIList {
    public static IList<T> Sort<T, TKey>(this IList<T> list, SortOrder sortOrder, Func<T, TKey> keySelector) {
            if (sortOrder == SortOrder.Descending) {
                return list.OrderByDescending(keySelector).ToList();
            } else {
                return list.OrderBy(keySelector).ToList();
            }
    }
}
```

and then you can use pretty with every your objects:

```
IList<Person> list = new List<Person>();

list.Add(new Person("David","Beckham"));
list.Add(new Person("Gennaro","Gattuso"));
list.Add(new Person("Cristian","Carlesso"));

list = list.Sort(SortOrder.Descending, X => X.Name);
```

ps SortOrder already exists:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like sorting is taking on a life of its own if you have several methods dedicated to it.  Maybe they can be gathered into a class.

```
public enum SortOrder
{
    Ascending = 0,
    Descending = 1
}
public class Sorter<T>
{
    public SortOrder Direction { get; set; }
    public Func<T, object> Target { get; set; }
    public Sorter<T> NextSort { get; set; }

    public IOrderedEnumerable<T> ApplySorting(IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        IOrderedEnumerable<T> result = Direction == SortOrder.Descending ?
            source.OrderByDescending(Target) : 
            source.OrderBy(Target);

        if (NextSort != null)
        {
            result = NextSort.ApplyNextSorting(result);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private IOrderedEnumerable<T> ApplyNextSorting
        (IOrderedEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        IOrderedEnumerable<T> result = Direction == SortOrder.Descending ?
            source.ThenByDescending(Target) :
            source.ThenBy(Target);
        return result;
    }
}
```

---

Here's sample usage:

```
List<string> source = new List<string>()
    { "John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo" };

Sorter<string> mySorter = new Sorter<string>()
{
    Target = s => s.Length,
    NextSort = new Sorter<string>()
    {
        Direction = SortOrder.Descending,
        Target = s => s
    }
};

foreach (string s in mySorter.ApplySorting(source))
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Output is Paul, John, Ringo, George.